# How to add prefix for resources in android open library?

Tags: android, shared-libraries

Now I'm writing an Android open source library. I had to upload it to jitpack.io.

I test it from a module by Gradle refer and find two problems:

1. Name conflict in `manifest.xml`

   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"

   I find resolution:

   tools:replace="android:icon"

   But this is not good. I should change the library, not the module which refers the library. How to?
2. Name conflicts in all resource when apk runs.

   I find resolution in gradle config file:

   resourcePrefix "unique_name_"

Now I can get a warning when I open any resource file, like: xxx is not a prefix, rename it?.....

But this is the only warning, no prefix be added automatically. I want to know:

1. if there is any way to add this prefix automatically when it sync, compiler or other time?
2. or if there is any shortcut key to confirm the rename action?

==========================

I do more test with other library. If I create a layout xml file which name is conflict with some other library's xml file, then app will crash when program run at the other library.

So it's strange why there is no automatic process option to avoid conflict between two modules or library? It is needed.